# Four fingered minimize with Touch ID alert on iOS 9

Tags: ios, ipad, ios9, touch-id

I just noticed that if a user enacts a 4 fingered minimize(pinch) on iOS 9 iPad, with the Touch ID alert displayed, the user is taken out of the app but the alert is still present. This is not possible with normal home button minimize, or four fingered swipe to go to a different app.

If a user finishes the touch ID flow, then the success block will get enacted when they go back into the app. This is not possible on iOS 8 since the four fingered minimize does not take the user out of the application when Touch ID alert is displayed.

I am curious if this is an Apple bug, or just new handling? My guess would be a bug, and I will report to Apple unless anyone else has insight into this?